# Shrinkehande graph?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

Shrinkhande graph is a graph which is a (16,6,2,2) strongly regular graph. It's well-known that it's a Cayley graph on group $Z_4\times Z_4$ with Cayley set $S=\{ ±(0,1),±(1,1),±(1,0)\}$. I'd like to know if we can define Cayley graph, associated to Shrinkhande graph on group $Z_2^4$. In fact I'm looking for the Cayley set. Besides I know this Cayley graph exists.

Comment: Since the generators of $C_2^4$ all have order $2$, you will need $6$ generators. You might as well choose the first four to be the natural generators, so you will have to find two more. I am sceptical about whether this is possible but I have no time to think about it now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of the 23 Cayley graphs for $\mathbb{Z}^4$ at http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/~00013890/. According to sage, in my hands,
none of these graphs is isomorphic to the Shrikande graph.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some magma code you can run to find all the regular subgroups of the automorphism group (and thus find all the groups on which it is Cayley):

---

G:=DirectProduct(CyclicGroup(4),CyclicGroup(4));
H:=sub< G|G.1,G.2,G.1*G.2>;
Gamma:=CayleyGraph(H:Directed:=false,Labelled:=false);
A:=AutomorphismGroup(Gamma);
for S in  Subgroups(A:IsRegular) do
IdentifyGroup(S`subgroup);
end for;

---

You can run this here:
http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/
and the output is:
<16, 2>
<16, 11>
<16, 6>
<16, 6>
<16, 8>
<16, 8>

We can then check say here:
https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/index.html
to find out what the groups are:
$C_4^2$, $SD_{16}$, $C_2\times D_4$, and $M_4(2)$.